# Creating patch files in git

Tags: git

I wanted to know whether it is possible to create patch files in git. I mean if I have done some changes in few files then patch file should be created with respect to the filename.

`git diff` displays the changes on the console but *Is it possible to separate 
 the output into different files?*

Comment: What do you mean too limited data? That's the way I usually create a patch, or  git diff master > filename.patch. When you patch it in you'll need to strip off the first part of the path with patch -p1 < filename.patch.

Comment: Sorry my bad @dj2 It saves successfully into single file but can it be saved to different files. for eg if file1 and file2 were modified can file1.patch and file2.patch be created for the same.

Comment: Why do you want to split the patch in individual files?

Comment: @t.niese The requirement is in such a way. I know I can achieve the same using eclipse. But is it possible using only git that is what I am wondering.

Comment: If you want each patch file contain the changes on a single file then put the file path into the [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) command. Is as easy as that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[git format-patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)

Say you've made a commit `aaa111` which modifies `foo.txt`, `bar.txt` and `hello.txt`.

`git format-patch -1 aaa111`

It generates a patch including three files' changes.

`git format-patch -1 aaa111 -- foo.txt`

It generates a patch including only the change of `foo.txt`.

`git format-patch -1 aaa111 --stdout -- bar.txt > aaa111.bar.patch`

It generates a patch named as `aaa111.bar.patch` which includes only the change of `bar.txt`

**Update 2022-06-04**

For the commit that touches binaries, you should add `--binary` to `git format-patch`.

Comment: @ElpieKay Can you explain what `-1` stands for (and what it is doing) please? I checked `git format-patch -h` but that isn't listed. Also, if I what to create patches for the recent 3 commits, each commit in one file, what should I do? thx.

Comment: @xpt `-h` lists only a few options. Use `git format-patch --help` or `man git format-patch` instead. `-1` is an instance of `-<n>`, which "prepares patches from the topmost <n> commits". Without `-1`, it creates patches for every commit reachable from `aaa111`. With `-1`, only the patch of `aaa111` is created. So with `git format-patch -3` it creates patches for the recent 3 commits. Note that `-<n>` is different from `-n`. Both are available options for `git format-patch`.

Answer (score 1):

The following script creates patches for the files modified on the most recent commit (`HEAD~1`):

```sh
# Enumerate the files modified on the desired commit
for file in $(git diff --name-only HEAD~1); do
    # Generate the name of the patch file: replac '/' with '_'
    # in the paths of the modified files and add the .patch termination
    patch=${file//\//_}.patch
    # Create one patch for each modified file
    git diff HEAD~1 -- $file > $patch
done
```

You can modify the generation of the patch file name to include a path (to not generate them in the current directory). Also to generate a diff between different commits, replace `HEAD~1` in both places with the appropriate commit(s) identifiers.